# Class model in C

Tags: c, class, struct, embedded

I'm trying to do a "class model" in C in which I define a `struct` that represents the class and inside it I define function pointers to represent methods, like this:

```
//ClassName.h

typedef struct struct_ClassName ClassName;

struct ClassName
{

    
    char a;

    char b;

    char c;

    

    void (*method1)(ClassName*, char);

    void (*method2)(ClassName*, char);

    ...

    void (*methodN)(ClassName*, char);

};

void initClassName(ClassName*);
```

```
//ClassName.c

#include "ClassName.h"

static void method1(ClassName *this_c, char c);
static void method2(ClassName *this_c, char c);
...
static void methodN(ClassName *this_c, char c);

void initClassName(ClassName *this_c)
{
    this_c->method1 = &method1;
    this_c->method2 = &method2;
    ...
    this_c->methodN = &methodN;
}

void method1(ClassName *this_c, char c)
{
    //do something
}

void method2(ClassName *this_c, char c)
{
    //do something
}

...


void methodN(ClassName *this_c, char c)
{
    //do something
}
```

Everything works fine but, somewhere in the code, I define an array:

```
...

ClassName objects[200];

for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    initClassName(&objects[i]);
}
...
```

Because of the function pointers, the memory usage associated to this array is quite high (I have several "methods" in this "class").

Considering that this is a code that will run in an embedded system, is there a better way to do it?

Defining functions outside the structure could be a possibility but in my opinion it does not respect what I'm trying to emulate.

I have to use **only C**, not C++.

Comment: Create a structure type containing the pointers to functions. Initialize one copy of it once.  Put a pointer to that structure in your class.  Use a level of indirection when invoking the functions.

Comment: You have found the downside of trying to emulate class methods in C! Is there any way you can use C++? Maybe not with a full C++ run-time environment, but for example, Arduino uses C++ with a small C++ run-time environment. @JonathonLeffler's suggestion is good, but it still wastes one pointer's worth of storage (plus alignment padding) per object.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes this may be a way

Comment: @IanAbbott unfortunately no, only C

Comment: Do you need the pointers in the structure? Can't you use the class name as a prefix?

Comment: @IanAbbot another possibility is to define functions outside of the structure, without use pointer but I see it as a bad practice and I don't like it

Comment: @thebusybee what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, as you say, define the function outside the structure. Please add to your question _why_ you see that as bad practice. -- C++ builds names from the class name and their individual name (and types), this is called name-mangling. You could use it explicitely.

Comment: start by using a constructor, a copy constructor and a destructor. Use this names and it will make life easier. And return pointers, not `void`. Look at `C++`.

Comment: @thebusybee Aren't you back to a good old imperative programming model and a naming convention at that point?

Comment: @IanAbbott Naming functions, API widths, and programming models are different beasts. What makes you think they are connected? The OP wants to use a language that does not quite support OOP, this leads to weird consequences. -- Concerning the name mangling, linkers don't know anything about programming models, they just need to differentiate the symbols. Therefore, you _need_ to do name mangling in OOP.

Comment: @thebusybee I edited the question. Could you please give me an example? I don't understand what you meant.

Comment: What are you _trying to emulate_ (your wording in the question)? -- If you want to call a method for an object, do it like this: `classNameMethod1(&obj, param);`. Granted, this pollutes the global namespace. Under the hood, C++ does the same. Did you read about name mangling and the problem it solves?

Comment: @thebusybee That's fine unless you need to implement virtual methods.

Comment: @IanAbbott Of course. That's why I asked the OP about the reasons for the pointers. Unfortunately there is no edition answering this. :-( -- In contrast to languages supporting this aspect of OOP, you could code `obj1.method1(&obj2, param);` :-P Happy debugging! -- However, virtual methods add pointers to the objects. The methods pointed to are still name-mangled, they need to.

Comment: @thebusybee I'm trying to emulate a class in C and I used function pointers in order to do `obj1.method1(&obj1, param);`, as you said. I find this approach _cleaner_ than defining functions outside the structure because it recall a real class in C++ but of course it's more expensive in terms of memory.

Comment: Well, then it is your choice: a (subjectively) cleaner style (with a chance of typoes) or less memory usage. Honestly, I see no way to have both.

Comment: @thebusybee okay, thank you! I think I'm gonna choose this way. I need less memory usage in order to run it in an embedded system, in the meantime I'll see if someone else can suggested something different.

Answer (score 6):

What you have created is a very dynamic system where each object instance can have its own set of method implementations. That's why it uses so much memory.

Another approach is an implementation closer to early C++ (before multiple inheritance) where all instance of the same class share the same *vtable*. The *vtable* contains the function pointers.

```
typedef struct struct_ClassName ClassName;

typedef struct struct_ClassName_vtable ClassName_vtable;

struct ClassName_vtable
{
    void (*method1)(ClassName*, char);
    void (*method2)(ClassName*, char);
    ...
    void (*methodN)(ClassName*, char);
}

struct ClassName
{
    ClassName_vtable* _vtable;
    
    char a;
    char b;
    char c;
};

void initClassName(ClassName*);
```

```
static void method1(ClassName *this_c, char c);
static void method2(ClassName *this_c, char c);
...
static void methodN(ClassName *this_c, char c);

ClassName_vtable _ClassName_vtable = {
    method1,
    method2,
    ...,
    methodN
};

void initClassName(ClassName *this_c)
{
    this_c->_vtable = _ClassName_vtable;
}
```

That way, the OO overhead per instance is only the size of a pointer. It's also easier to create subclasses.

A method call looks like this:

```
ClassName* obj = ...;
obj->vtable->method2(obj, 'a');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ClassName objects[200];

for(i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    initClassName(&objects[i]);
```

I will show you a *stripped-off* version of something I use here
for similar effect. It is hard to say when a certain size is huge in terms of pointers or whatever. Each environment has their truth and this can be useless or useful...

Anyway, the ideia is encapsulation. And in C we have no *this* pointer. `C` is not `C++` or `java` or `javascript`. Each class instance must have a table of function pointers for the methods. We need to build these tables. This is how *virtual classes* are implemented in others languages anyway. And if each class element can allocate memory code is needed to allocate and free memory.

### TL;DR

Below is a C example of a program that builds and uses an array of classes. In this case an array of **stacks**. It shows a mechanism of building stacks of mixed things. Each array item has all that is needed to manage his own stack instance, be it of a trivial type or a complex structure. It can be easily changed to implement other tyoes of `classes` in C.

Please do not bother warning me that I cast the return of `malloc()`. I , as many others, do not like implicit things. And I know that C-FAQ is a never-updated thing from the end of the '90s so no need to reference this either.

### An example: a static `STACK` container

```
typedef struct
{
    int data[SIZE];
    int limit; // capacity  
    int size; // actual
}   Stack;
```

This is it: a simple stack of `int` values. Let us say we want to declare a vector of stacks of different things, but in C. And use methods on them. If we use trivial types --- in C++ we say the struct is [trivialy constructible](https://cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_trivially_constructible/)  --- things can get easier, but if we are about to use structs we need to know about how to manipulate stack elements, since they can allocate memory.
We are writing a container so the methods of the class must work for any underlying data. And we have no *iterators* like `C++ STL`. Here we are implementing the `POP` `TOP` and `PUSH` methods for stacks, and a `toString()` method like in `java` to print values on the screen.

For each possible content in the container we need to have a constructor, a
destructor, a copy constructor and a display method. In this example we have just 2 types of stacks: a stack of `int` and a stack of `struct Sample`:

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t _id;
    char   name[30];
    char   phone[20];
} Sample;
```

We can add others just by writing the required 4 functions.

#### `main.c` example

```
int main(void)
{
    srand(220804); // for the factory functions

    Stack* class_array[2] = {
        create(4, create_i, copy_i, destroy_i, show_i),
        create(3, create_st, copy_st, destroy_st, show_st)};

    printf("\n\n=====> Testing with STACK of int\n\n");
    class_test(class_array[0], factory_i);
    printf(
        "\n\n=====> Testing with STACK of struct "
        "Sample\n\n");
    class_test(class_array[1], factory_st);

    class_array[0]->destroy(class_array[0]);
    class_array[1]->destroy(class_array[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Each instance of `Stack` has pointers to the stack methods and to the functions that manipulate the stack data, so we can have a single `class_test()` function that does the following:

- builds a stack of the required size, 4 or 3 in the example
- fills the stack with data generated by factory functions (in production the logic builds the data)
- shows the stack contents
- removes all stack elements, one by one

At the end the destructor is called for eack stack.

#### The `class.h` file

```
typedef void* (PVFV)(void*);
typedef int   (PIFV)(void*);

typedef struct
{
    size_t size_;
    size_t lim_;
    void** data_;

    PVFV* copy;
    PVFV* destroy;
    int (*show)(void*,const char*); // for testing
    // constructor and destructor for container elements
    PVFV* create_1;
    PVFV* copy_1;
    PVFV* destroy_1;
    PIFV* show_1;
    // member functions
    PIFV* POP;
    int (*PUSH)(void*,void*);
    PVFV* TOP;
    PIFV* empty;
    size_t (*size)(void*);

} Stack;

Stack* create(
    size_t, 
    void* (*)(void*),
    void* (*)(void*),
    void* (*)(void*),
    int   (*)(void*));

int class_test(Stack*, void* (*)());
```

#### the example output

```
=====> Testing with STACK of int

Stack is empty
POP() on empty stack returned -2
TOP() on empty stack returned NULL
Calls PUSH until error

Value inserted: 42
Value inserted: 41
Value inserted: 40
Value inserted: 39
Stack now has 4 elements

Stack has 4 of 4 elements:

 42
 41
 40
 39


Calls POP() until error
Stack size: 3
Stack size: 2
Stack size: 1
Stack size: 0


=====> Testing with STACK of struct Sample

Stack is empty
POP() on empty stack returned -2
TOP() on empty stack returned NULL
Calls PUSH until error

Value inserted:  0195   Sample id#0195      +76(203)6840-195
Value inserted:  0943   Sample id#0943      +35(686)9368-943
Value inserted:  0152   Sample id#0152      +16(051)8816-152
Stack now has 3 elements

Stack has 3 of 3 elements:

  0096   Sample id#0096      +24(477)0418-096
  0037   Sample id#0037      +27(214)3509-037
  0836   Sample id#0836      +68(857)4634-836


Calls POP() until error
Stack size: 2
Stack size: 1
Stack size: 0
```

#### the logic

For each tye of element we need to write the 4 functions: they can alocate memory and be very complex or they can be trivial, but the class methods need to handle any case.

#### code for `struct Sample` in `stack_struct.h`###

```
#pragma once
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* copy_st(void*);
void* create_st(void*);
void* destroy_st(void*);
void* factory_st();

typedef struct
{
    size_t _id;
    char   name[30];
    char   phone[20];
} Sample;

void* create_st(void* el)
{
    return factory_st();
}

void* copy_st(void* el)
{
    if (el == NULL) return NULL;
    Sample* e = (Sample*)malloc(sizeof(Sample));
    *e     = *((Sample*)el);
    return e;
}

void* destroy_st(void* el)
{
    if (el == NULL) return NULL;
    free(el);
    return NULL;
}

int show_st(void* el)
{
    if (el == NULL) return 0;
    Sample* e = (Sample*)el;
    printf(
        "  %04d  %15s  %20s\n",
        (int) e->_id, e->name, e->phone);
    return 0;
}

void* factory_st()
{
    Sample* e = (Sample*)malloc(sizeof(Sample));
    e->_id    = rand() % 1000;
    sprintf(e->name, "Sample id#%04d", (int)e->_id);
    memset(e->phone, 0, sizeof(e->phone));
    e->phone[0] = '+';
    for (int i = 1; i <= 17; i += 1)
        e->phone[i] = '0' + rand() % 10;
    e->phone[3]  = '(';
    e->phone[7]  = ')';
    e->phone[12] = '-';
    e->phone[13] = e->name[11];
    e->phone[14] = e->name[12];
    e->phone[15] = e->name[13];
    e->phone[16] = e->name[14];
    e->phone[17] = 0;
    return (void*)e;
}
```

#### code for `int` elements `stack_int.h`_###

```
#pragma once
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* create_i(void* el)
{
    int* e = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *e     = *((int*)el);
    return (void*)e;
}

void* copy_i(void* el)
{
    if (el == NULL) return NULL;
    int* e = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *e     = *( (int*)el );
    return e;
}

void* destroy_i(void* el)
{
    if (el == NULL) return NULL;
    free(el);
    return NULL;
}

int show_i(void* el)
{
    if (el == NULL) return 0;
    int v = *((int*)el);
    printf(" %d\n", v);
    return 0;
}

void* factory_i()
{
    static int i       = 42;
    int*       new_int = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *new_int           = i;
    i -= 1;
    return (void*)new_int;
}
```

#### The class implementation `class.c`

```
#include "class.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void*  Copy__(void*);
void*  Destroy__(void*);
int    POP__(void*);
int    PUSH__(void*, void*);
int    Show__(void*, const char*);
void*  TOP__(void*);
int    empty__(void*);
size_t size__(void*);

Stack* create(
    size_t sz, void* (*create)(void*), void* (*copy)(void*),
    void* (*destroy)(void*), int (*show)(void*))
{
    Stack* stack = (Stack*)malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;
    stack->size_ = 0;
    stack->lim_  = sz;
    stack->data_ = (void*)malloc(sz * sizeof(void*));

    stack->copy    = Copy__;
    stack->destroy = Destroy__;
    stack->show    = Show__;

    stack->create_1  = create;
    stack->copy_1    = copy;
    stack->destroy_1 = destroy;
    stack->show_1    = show;

    stack->POP  = POP__;
    stack->PUSH = PUSH__;
    stack->TOP  = TOP__;

    stack->empty = empty__;
    stack->size  = size__;

    return stack;
}

void* Copy__(void* one) { return NULL; };

void* Destroy__(void* stack)
{  // before destructing a stack we need to
    // destroy all elements
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;
    Stack* st = (Stack*)stack;
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < st->size_; ix += 1)
        (st->destroy_1)(st->data_[ix]);
    free(st->data_);
    free(st);
    return NULL;
};
int POP__(void* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;  // no stack
    Stack* st = stack;
    if (st->size_ == 0) return -2;  // empty
    st->size_ -= 1;                 // one less
    return 0;                       // ok
}

int PUSH__(void* el, void* stack)
{
    if (el == NULL) return -1;     // no element
    if (stack == NULL) return -2;  // no stack
    Stack* st = (Stack*)stack;
    if (st->size_ == st->lim_) return -3;  // full
    void* new_el = st->create_1(el);       // copy construct
    st->data_[st->size_] = new_el;
    st->size_ += 1;  // one up
    return 0;        // ok
}

int Show__(void* stack, const char* title)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return -1;
    Stack* st = stack;
    if (title != NULL) printf("%s\n", title);
    if (st->size_ == 0)
    {
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (size_t ix = 0; ix < st->size_; ix += 1)
        st->show_1(st->data_[ix]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

void* TOP__(void* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return NULL;  // no stack
    Stack* st = stack;
    if (st->size_ == 0) return NULL;  // empty
    return st->data_[st->size_ - 1];  // ok
}

int empty__(void* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return 1;  // empty??
    return ((Stack*)stack)->size_ == 0;
}

size_t size__(void* stack)
{
    if (stack == NULL) return 1;  // empty??
    return ((Stack*)stack)->size_;
}


///////////// TEST FUNCTION ///////////////

int class_test(Stack* tst, void* (*factory)())
{
    if (tst == NULL) return -1;
    // is stack empty?
    if (tst->empty(tst))
        printf("Stack is empty\n");
    else
        printf("Stack: %zd elements\n", tst->size(tst));

    int res = tst->POP(tst);
    printf("POP() on empty stack returned %d\n", res);

    void* top = tst->TOP(tst);
    if (top == NULL)
        printf("TOP() on empty stack returned NULL\n");
    else
    {
        printf(
            "\nTOP() on empty stack returned NOT NULL!\n");
        return -2;
    }

    printf("Calls PUSH until error\n\n");
    void* one   = factory();
    int   value = *(int*)one;
    while (tst->PUSH(one, tst) == 0)
    {
        printf("Value inserted:");
        tst->show_1(one);
        free(one);
        one = factory();
    }
    free(one);  // last one, not inserted
    printf("Stack now has %zd elements\n", tst->size(tst));

    char title[80] = {" "};
    sprintf(
        title, "\nStack has %zd of %zd elements:\n",
        tst->size_, tst->lim_);
    tst->show(tst, title);

    // agora esvazia a pilha ate dar erro
    printf("\nCalls POP() until error\n");
    while (tst->POP(tst) == 0)
        printf("Stack size: %I32d\n", (int)tst->size(tst));
    return 0;
};
```

#### The complete `main.c` program

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "class.h"
#include "stack_int.h"
#include "stack_struct.h"

int main(void)
{
    srand(220804);

    Stack* class_array[2] = {
        create(4, create_i, copy_i, destroy_i, show_i),
        create(3, create_st, copy_st, destroy_st, show_st)};

    printf("\n\n=====> Testing with STACK of int\n\n");
    class_test(class_array[0], factory_i);
    printf(
        "\n\n=====> Testing with STACK of struct "
        "Sample\n\n");
    class_test(class_array[1], factory_st);

    class_array[0]->destroy(class_array[0]);
    class_array[1]->destroy(class_array[1]);

    return 0;
}
```